# Adding fields to datasets through GUI in SAS EG

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I would like to add a couple of fields to an existing dataset in SAS EG.  Can I do this through a properties dialog, without having to write code?

Comment: FYI, I recommend http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/ as a great point to start learning EG - Chris was one of the EG developers for years and is a very entertaining writer, with tons of great hints and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in Update mode (easiest way - double click on any cell, choose yes), you can right click on a column header (the variable label up top) where you want to insert the new one and select "Insert Column".

Answer (score 0):

you need to open table (douple clic on it) and try to edit (double click on the row filed) -> in pop up window select to transfer table in update mode. After its done, select whole row and in right click menu u will see add or delete rows options. 
p.s. you can also add coloumns via similar manipulations.